# Trying to get property of non-object error with thumbnail

Tags: errors

I'm trying to get the thumbnail of my featured image to display on my home.php (blog) page.

It is displaying fine, but when debugging mode is turned on, I get this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wpflat/wp-content/themes/wpflat/content-blog.php on line 2

My code is

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->id, 'thumbnail'); ?></a>
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: You need to show more code. What is `$page? `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe from your error that you are using this code inside the loop. You should be using [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail). The code you are using is used outside the loop.

**EDIT**

It is always good practice to always first check [if you have a thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail) to display

So you should use

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail'); ?>
   </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Great. Your code worked.  Thanks a lot!!

The image was in the loop, however the issue was that I added $page->id to the code when I should have left it out. That is why it came with the error "Trying to get property of non-object"